# Invalid Syntax confusion on Python Integers

Tags: python

We know that everything is an object in Python and so that includes integers. So doing `dir(34)` is no surprise, there are attributes available.

My confusion stems from the following, why is it that doing `34.__class__` gives a syntax error when I know that `34` does have the attribute `__class__`. Furthermore, why does binding an integer to a name, say `x`, and then doing `x.__class__` yield my expected answer of type int?

Comment: . is used for the decimal point. You can not do `34()` either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `34.__class__` is not a valid floating-point number, which is what the `.` denotes in a numeric literal. Try `(34).__class__`.

Comment: Oh doh. So the `.` is the syntax that tells python when a number is a float or int? Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it's a decimal point when used with a number.

Comment: Also consider that `1.e3` is a perfectly valid float literal; how could you distinguish that from the member `e3` of the int `1` if both were allowed?

Comment: Yeah, you'd be forced to write that as `1.0e3 or `1e3`... which would be OK I guess.